# Android 9 (AOSP) will boot only if mdns socket is opened in system/etc/init/netd.rc

Tags: android, android-source, init, boot

Why would an mdns socket required for AOSP 9 to run?

```
socket mdns stream 0660 root system
```

When this line in AOSP 9 source code in (system)/etc/init/netd.rc is commented out, the boot does not proceed past the Android logo.

Interesting that deleting mdnsd daemon in (system)/bin does not affect the boot process.  Thank you!

Comment: From the source code it looks like ADB is setting mDNS up, but to make mDNS socket a prerequisite to boot? Still looking into this all...

Comment: Seems like netd/server/main.cpp exits if mDNSListener cannot be started. Ludicrous?